# Outlook Interop add body text

Tags: c#, windows, outlook, ms-word, office-interop

*Updated to try and make the question more readable, following comments below*

**Scenario:**
user clicks reply in outlook 365 this opens a mailItem within the main window of outlook. we are attempting to add text to the body of this mailItem.

Currently my method can add text to the to and cc field of the imbedded mailItem but not the body. It will add text to the body, To, Cc, and Subject of a modal mailItem, with this modal open it will even add text to the mailItem's body that it would not work with previously.

When only the main window is open, the focusedClass is not present, so it hits the SendMessage method.

**Question:**
How do you add text to the body of this mailItem? When only the main Outlook window is open and the MailItem is imbedded in the main window.

So far I have looked at Spy++ and the Z order always changes so I cannot find a logical way to get a child window to work with, plus the structure for the mailItem is different while in the main window and modal.

My current solution uses GetWindowThreadProcessId and  GetCurrentThreadId to get the focused window, then the GetFocusClass to find the class, with this class obtained we finally call the below to insert the text:

```
 if (focusedClass.ToLower() == "_wwg")
                InsertTextToEmailBody(text);
            else
                SendMessage(focused, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, newText);
```

```
private void InsertTextToEmailBody(string text)
        {
            var outlookApplication = GetOulookApplication();
            var activityInspector = outlookApplication.ActiveInspector();
            var currentItem = activityInspector?.CurrentItem;

            if (currentItem == null)
            {
                _log.Error("InsertTextToEmailBody could not find CurrentItem and cannot inject into email body");
                return;
            }

            var myInspector = ((MailItem) currentItem).GetInspector;
            var wdDoc = (Document) myInspector.WordEditor;
            var currentSelection = wdDoc.Application.Selection;

            if (currentSelection.Range?.Text?.Length > 0)
            {
                //The user has a selected range of text, replace that with transcription
                currentSelection.Range.Text = text;
                return;
            }

            // Store the user's current Overtype selection
            var userOvertype = wdDoc.Application.Options.Overtype;

            // Make sure Overtype is turned off.
            if (wdDoc.Application.Options.Overtype) wdDoc.Application.Options.Overtype = false;

            // Test to see if selection is an insertion point.
            if (currentSelection.Type == WdSelectionType.wdSelectionIP)
                currentSelection.TypeText(text);
            else if (currentSelection.Type == WdSelectionType.wdSelectionNormal)
            {
                // Move to start of selection.
                if (wdDoc.Application.Options.ReplaceSelection)
                {
                    object direction = WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;
                    currentSelection.Collapse(ref direction);
                }

                currentSelection.TypeText(text);
            }

            // Restore the user's Overtype selection
            wdDoc.Application.Options.Overtype = userOvertype;
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking since your code seems to be using WOM and I don't see any obvious problems with it. Does it not work?

Comment: I thought the question was laid out in a clear enough manner to understand, though I apologise if it isnt obvious.

TLDR is the class isnt found and the send message is not working

Comment: So what is wrong with the code? Which line errors out or behaves unexpectedly? Why not just set the MailItem.HTMLBody property? Does the text need to be inserted in a particular position?

Comment: By "class", do you mean a window with a particular window class is not found? But you never posted any code that actually looks for a window with a particular class.

Comment: Are you trying to get HWND of the Word editor control?

Comment: Again, focusedClass is not found so it hits the else statement and SendMessage(focused, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, newText); This does not work when you only have the main window of Outlook open, though having a modal window open it does send the text to the modal mailItems body and the main window imbedded mailItem.

Comment: Are you trying to get HWND of the Word editor control?
As covered I am using GetWindowThreadProcessId to get the the current focused, using this class to confirm we are in the Outlook mailItem body by checking "_wwg". Again as covered above we could not use Windows method to get children as the Z index for the windows changes, and I cannot guarantee the next window is what I expect it to be.

Comment: Again, you are not including any code that actually looks for a window with the particular message class. That's the code that you are having problems with, right? And why are you working with a focused window? What if the user has the cursor in the Subject or To edit box?

Comment: We are inserting the text where the cursor is that is why, I have told you how we are getting the window. The code is using GetWindowThreadProcessId which I thought was a generic enough approach to not need shared:

Comment: var remoteThreadId = WinUserDlls.GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowProcessId, out _);
            var currentThreadId = WinUserDlls.GetCurrentThreadId();
            //AttachTrheadInput is needed so we can get the handle of a focused window in another app
            var attached = WinUserDlls.AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, remoteThreadId, true);
            var focused = WinUserDlls.GetFocus();
            //Now detach since we got the focused handle
            var dettached = WinUserDlls.AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, remoteThreadId, false);

            return focused;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to use `GetFocus()` etc. to find the `HWND` of the Word editor - the focus can be anywhere in the Inspector (e.g. Subject or To edit box), plus clicking on the ribbon can take the focus away from the Word editor even if it was there to begin with.

What works for me is the following:

1. QI/cast your `Inspector` object (e.g. retrieved from from `Application.ActiveInspector`) to `IOleWindow`. Call `IOleWindows.GetWindow()` to get the top level `HWND` of the inspector.
2. Call `EnumChildWindows` with a callback that calls `GetClassName` and compares it with `"_WwG"`. Note that in Office 12 and older the class name is `"_WwF"`.

I also not sure what is wrong with your code that uses Word Object Model to insert text. It looks perfectly fine to me (without actually debugging it), and it would be the preferable solution since it would work out-of-proc since `SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)` requires that both the caller and the target window are in the same process (since it takes a pointer to a text buffer).

Comment: To be clear we want to inject text to the to, subject, cc, and bcc if that is where focus is not just the main body.